# Is this formula regarding rate of change and logs exact or an approximation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Suppose that a variable grows $5\%$ each year:

$$\frac{Y_t}{Y_{t-1}} = 1.05$$

Is it exactly equivalent (or at least aproximately equivalent) to

$$y_t = y_{t-1} + 0.05$$

where $y_t = \ln(Y_t)$ ? Why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not exactly.

You have $$\ln\left(\frac{Y_t}{Y_{t-1}}\right) = \ln(1.05) \implies$$

$$\ln(Y_t)-\ln(Y_{t-1})=\ln(1.05) \implies$$

$$y_t=y_{t-1}+\ln(1.05).$$

Now use a well-know Taylor expansion, $\ln(1+x)\approx x$, that is valid for small $x$ (the smaller $x$ is, the better the approximation) to see why $\ln(1.05)=0.04879\cdots \approx 0.05$.

Comment: @SamuelBarbosa No problem. If you find that it answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick found under the up/down-vote buttons. This will take the question off of the "unanswered list" and make the author of the answer happy, as it gives a boost of reputation (it will also give the person asking the question a small increase in reputation as well). Note that you can only accept one answer per question you ask. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I tried to upvote but I do not have enough reputation (less than 15).

Comment: @SamuelBarbosa Again, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

$Y_t = 1.05 Y_{t-1} \implies \ln Y_t = \ln  Y_{t-1} + \ln 1.05$

For $t$ close to $0$ $\ln (1+t) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n} t^n$. As $t=0.05$ the first term of the series is also $0.05$.

So your equality is useful for quick calculations but not totally correct.

Comment: How do you relate $ln(1+t)$ to that infinite series?

Comment: It's just Taylor series